# RCUTILS_SET_ERROR_MSG and RMW_SET_ERROR_MSG output and behavior

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [doxygen](http://docs.ros2.org/eloquent/api/rcutils/error__handling_8h.html#a1deacfdced935d6fa2f739bdbeb8e0b1) and this [line](https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/blob/master/include/rcutils/error_handling.h#L194), `RCUTILS_SET_ERROR_MSG()` should produce output if `rcutils_reset_error` wasn't called and "this library" (assuming RCL) was built with the `RCUTILS_REPORT_ERROR_HANDLING_ERRORS` flag set. I see that the build flag is set [here](https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/blob/master/src/allocator.c#L28) and [here](https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/blob/master/src/error_handling_helpers.h#L25).

Since there are many of the `RCUTILS_SET_ERROR_MSG` (and `RMW_SET_ERROR_MSG`) calls in RCL and RMW, I expect to see some of these outputs to `stderr`, `stdout`, or a log file somewhere on occasion.

1. What am I missing to turn these prints on and where to do they actually go?
2. Do I need to build ROS2 from source to enable this output with some other flags set or would the precompiled binaries have this capability innately?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348867/rcutils_set_error_msg-and-rmw_set_error_msg-output-and-behavior/) by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2020-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Partially reproducing what I've written elsewhere, `rcutils` error handling is somewhat similar to POSIX errno based error handling. There's a global error state, that in this case is populated with an arbitrary string, and functions let calling code know there was an error in some way -- often using a well-known numeric return code, but sometimes it may be something else. From then on, it is up to calling code to decide on what should be done with that (string) error state.

Thus,

1. `*_SET_ERROR_MSG` macros are not conditionally-compilable print or logging macros. They set an error state. Where, when, how and even if that error state is eventually made visible is entirely up to client code up in the stack. `RCUTILS_REPORT_ERROR_HANDLING_ERRORS` purpose is not to turn some of these macros into prints, but to avoid masking errors by printing the error state that is about to be overwritten in the hypothetical case in which client code does poor error handling (i.e. it reports errors with error handling itself).
2. Question is based on an invalid assumption/expectation.

Hope this clarifies things a bit.

---

Originally posted by [hidmic](https://answers.ros.org/users/24051/hidmic/) with karma: 121 on 2020-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0